# Why does a lambda incorporated with the argument directly in brackets not give me the desired output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, arguments

When I write this:

```
def calculator(operation, n1, n2):
    return operation(n1, n2)`

print (calculator(lambda n1, n2: n1 * n2, 10, 20))
```

I get the desired output of 200.

But when I write this:

```
print (lambda n1,n2: n1*n2 (10,20))
```

I do not get 200 as the output.

Why is this so?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to wrap your `lambda` assignment within paranthesis `()` as below:

```
print((lambda n1, n2: n1 * n2)(10, 20))
```

Prints:

```
200
```

Alternatively, you can assign the `lambda` expression to a variable, and then use the variable:

```py
l = lambda n1, n2: n1 * n2
print(l(10, 20))
```

Comment: Oh cool. Thanks

Comment: No problem! glad it was able to help

Comment: @Anonymous also, remember to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer if it helped :-)